# HTML Form crashes entire page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a form that accepts 5 inputs and sets each passed form as a cell in the table. This works if I fill in only four of my five elements, but if I fill in all the options it crashes. I want to add a row to the table only when all of the five elements of the form have been filled in by the user.

```js
function aFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable"),
    row = table.insertRow(-1),
    cell1 = row.insertCell(0),
    cell2 = row.insertCell(1),
    cell3 = row.insertCell(2),
    cell4 = row.insertCell(3),
    cell5 = row.insertCell(4),
    elements = document.forms['myForm'].elements;

  cell1.innerHTML = elements['pickup'].value;
  cell2.innerHTML = elements['delivery'].value;
  cell3.innerHTML = elements['price'].value;
  cell4.innerHTML = elements['pickup-distance'].value;
  cell5.innerHTML = elements['delivery-distance'].value;

}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

body {
  background-color: powderblue;
}

h1 {
  color: red;
}

p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Pickup Address</th>
    <th>Delivery Address</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Distance to Pickup</th>
    <th>Delivery Distance</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<form style="border:1px solid #ccc" id="myForm">
  <div class="container">

    <p>Please fill in this form to post a job for our drivers.</p>
    <hr>

    <label for="pickup-address"><b>Pickup Address</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Address" name="pickup" required>

    <label for="delivery-address"><b>Delivery Address</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Address" name="delivery" required>

    <label for="price"><b>Price</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Price" name="price" required>

    <label for="distance-to-pickup"><b>Distance to Pickup</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter distance" name="pickup-distance" required>

    <label for="distance-to-delivery"><b>Distance to Delivery</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter distance" name="delivery-distance" required>

    <button onclick="aFunction()">Post</button>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Define the problem more clearly. What do you mean "crash"? Do you get an error? If so, what exactly is it? I can fill out all the field and submit here with no issues.

Comment: When you say "crashes", do you mean there's an error? Or, that the page reloads? To prevent a reload, you would need to call `event.preventDefault` in your `aFunction`, which I don't see. OR, add an `action` to your form to submit your data.

Comment: @Jack I don't see him actually submitting a form so the problem isn't that the page reloads.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine The default action of a `<button>` within a `<form>` is `submit`.

Comment: @TylerRoper thanks, good to know! Looks like thats dependent on the browser though based on scamtex answer

Comment: @IsaacVidrine W3schools isn't exactly the best resource (as I'd mentioned on that answer). Per the [official W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element): *The missing value default [for `type`] is the Submit Button state. If the element has a form owner, the element must submit the form owner from the button element."*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define the *type* of button, i.e.:

```html
<button onclick="aFunction()" type="button">Post</button>
```

to prevent the submitting of the form and reloading (doesn't really crash) the page.

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) on buttons:

> Always specify the type attribute for a  element. Different browsers use different default types for the  element.

Comment: Nice answer! The only *miniscule* thing I might suggest going forward is that historically, W3Schools hasn't exactly been seen as the *best* development resource, and as such some people (warranted or not) dock some credibility from answers that cite it. May I suggest [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Notes) as a much more welcome alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `document.getElementsByTagName("input")` instead of `document.forms['myForm'].elements;`

```js
function aFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable"),
    row = table.insertRow(-1),
    cell1 = row.insertCell(0),
    cell2 = row.insertCell(1),
    cell3 = row.insertCell(2),
    cell4 = row.insertCell(3),
    cell5 = row.insertCell(4),
    elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input")//document.forms['myForm'].elements;
//console.log(elements)
  cell1.innerHTML = elements[0].value;
  cell2.innerHTML = elements[1].value;
  cell3.innerHTML = elements[2].value;
  cell4.innerHTML = elements[3].value;
  cell5.innerHTML = elements[4].value;

}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

body {
  background-color: powderblue;
}

h1 {
  color: red;
}

p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Pickup Address</th>
    <th>Delivery Address</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Distance to Pickup</th>
    <th>Delivery Distance</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<div style="border:1px solid #ccc" id="myForm">
  <div class="container">

    <p>Please fill in this form to post a job for our drivers.</p>
    <hr>

    <label for="pickup-address"><b>Pickup Address</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Address" name="pickup" required>

    <label for="delivery-address"><b>Delivery Address</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Address" name="delivery" required>

    <label for="price"><b>Price</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Price" name="price" required>

    <label for="distance-to-pickup"><b>Distance to Pickup</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter distance" name="pickup-distance" required>

    <label for="distance-to-delivery"><b>Distance to Delivery</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter distance" name="delivery-distance" required>

    <button onclick="aFunction()">Post</button>

  </div>
</div>
```